# Usage of "age" in a quote

Tags: british-english

How should we use the word *age* in the quote below ?

> Friendship never age, it just deepens.

Or

> Friendship never ages, it just deepens.

I'm not that strong with grammar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be *friendship never ages*. The word *ages* has got to have that *s* at the end of it because the subject *friendship* is a third-person singular noun and with third-person singular nouns, verbs that accompany them must end in *s*. That's the rule.

I'm guessing the confusion arises from the fact that when we negate a sentence whose subject is a third-person singular noun, the *s* at the end of the main verb usually disappears. For instance:

> He **likes** ice cream. -----> He **does not like** ice cream.

As you can see, the *s* at the end of the main verb *likes* vanishes when the sentence is negated. However, this does not apply to negative words like *never* because they're just that—words like all other words in English. It's only the word *not*, when used as part of the negation process, that has this power of stripping verbs off their *s*'s. That's why with *never*, there has to be an *s* at the end of the main verb:

> He **smokes** in front of this children. -----> He **never smokes** in front of his children.

And as I mentioned above, the adverb *never* is no different than any other adverb:

> He **smokes** in front of this children. -----> He **sometimes smokes** in front of his children.
>
> He **smokes** in front of this children. -----> He **often smokes** in front of his children.

I hope my explanation makes sense to you and does not sound like a ramble.